# how to remove href for "printing" html to PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I build HTML pages and I would like to let the user "print" the HTML to a PDF, without embedding the HREF links (because they link to an internal server, and I do not want the readers of the PDF to see these links).

In Chromium, the resulting PDF file embeds the href links.

Is is possible to remove the hrefs via CSS of Javascript?

I tried this:

```
<a class="no_print" href="javascript:printPreview()">Print Preview</a>

<script>
function printPreview() {
    var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var atl = aTags.length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < atl; i++) {
        aTags[i].href = ''; 
    }
}
</script>
```

but is does not work.

-- edit: after the solution was found, here is a complete example --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><header>
    <title>x</title>
    <style>
        @media print { .no_print { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script>
function printPreview()
{
    var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var atl = aTags.length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < atl; i++) {
        aTags[i].removeAttribute("href");   
    }
}
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a class="no_print" href="javascript:printPreview()">Print Preview</a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://example.com">link to somewhere</a>
    <br>
    <a>anchor but no link</a>
    <br>
    other text...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: put your `.no_print` css class inside `@media print { ... }`

Comment: It should probably be `function printPreview()`

Comment: Yes use `@media print { .no_print { display: none; } }` in your css. Don't use javascript for this.

Comment: _because they link to an internal server_. Can they not see it on the actual website where they have to click _print preview_ anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which works fine.

```
<html>
  <a class="no_print" href="javascript:printPreview()">Print Preview</a>

  <script>
  function printPreview() {
     var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
     var atl = aTags.length;
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < atl; i++) {
        **aTags[i].removeAttribute("href");**
     }  
  }
  </script>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below JS

```
 function printPreview() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body a').each(function(index, element) {
     element.removeAttribute('href');
    });
}
```

the above code will remove href attribute for all anchor inside body.

Answer (score 1):

Try sth. like that maybe?

**HTML**

```
<a class="no_print" href="javascript:printPreview">Print Preview</a>
```

**JS**

```
function printPreview() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('a').removeAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: your answer drove me to the solution, but user3752326 answered more accurately

Answer (score 0):

Pure css solution:

```
@media print {
    a:after {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```